# Any chance access raw pixel regardless of screen resolution on windows/linux

Tags: windows, graphic

If the LCD display is 1920*1200(native resolution), the screen resolution is set to 1024*768.

Any chance I can create a buffer with 1920*1200 size, and blt is pixel-by-pixel to the screen on Windows or Linux, without downscale it to 1024*768 first?

Thanks.

Comment: There are scalers in most LCD monitors, in which case the native resolution image doesn't even exist in your computer.

Answer (score 3):

No.

Some [novel displays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_paper) retain the image and update it pixel by pixel, but conventional computer displays don't work like this.

The computer sends an entire image to the display fifty (or more) times per second.  If your computer is configured with a 1024x768 resolution, then that's how many pixels are sent to the monitor.  If the monitor actually has more pixels then it will either letterbox the image or upscale it to the native resolution.

To display your 1920x1200 image when the resolution is set to 1024x768 you do need to downscale it.

Comment: This is really a bad design, IMHO. I think the graphic driver should provide this possibility, anyway. I can not imagine why this gonna be a big effort...

Comment: You can change the screen resolution in the context of your application.  A lot of games do this.  But it's not a great solution for just displaying a picture because there tends to be a bit of flicker and a small delay while the display adapter and the display adjust themselves.